# Where does selenium generates the test execution logs? // selenium grid // docker

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose

I am trying to run Selenium test cases inside docker through Jenkins. The docker is on Amazon EC2 instance. I start docker with the following command:

```
docker run -d -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home:z -p 80:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v "/home/ec2-user/source/jenkins" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v $(which docker-compose):/usr/bin/docker-compose  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Below is the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.14
    ports: 
    - "443:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.14
    ports: 
    - "9000:5900"
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.14
    shm_size: '1gb'
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub
  test-module:
    image: pu/tc
    depends_on:
      - chrome
      - firefox
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub
      - BROWSER=chrome
      - MODULE=testng.xml
    volumes:
      - ./output/test-result:/home/ec2-user/test-output
```

The yaml file creates one chrome, one firefox, and one hub docker instances. I want to know where does it store the test case execution logs and reports?

I have already checked `/dev/shm` location inside the chrome docker instance, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It stores the logs where your test code is running. If it is running in `test-module` and put the results to `/home/ec2-user/test-output` of the container then it can be found either there in the container or where you have started your `docker-compose` under `./output/test-result`

Comment: I checked this /home/ec2-user/test-output location inside chrome container and this directory doesn’t exist.

Comment: It either has to be created when you build docker image or by your tests. If your tests expect that folder to exist then they might fail. From docker standpoint everything is straightforward. If is does not exist then the information in your question is not enough to give you the right answer.

Comment: Thanks. A couple of more questions:

1.) Will it create in docker? Or docker-chrome instance? Or docker selenium hub instance? 
2.) Do I have to manually create this directory?

Comment: No.. wait.. It has not to exist in chrome container. Look for it in `test-module` container. I've just run your compose and the folder is there.

Comment: Thank you! I do see `test-module_1` container, but I am unable to login. It just exist in a few seconds. 

https://ibb.co/jfpVVB0

Do you see the test report also in the `test-output` folder?

Comment: Sorry I can't see anything there because I have no access to your `pu/tc` image. I just created a model of your case. Your container is stopped because it finished the process that was running in it. Either test was finished or the process existed abnormally. For further investigation we need to see what image are you using and what are your tests.